# How to solve Android Firebase No setter/field Problem?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I want to receive messages sent to the user according to the message ID number. However, I could not fix the No setter / field error.

How to resolve this problem? What is the method?

## Messages Java Class

```
public class Messages {
private String sendMessage;
private long timestamp;

public String getSendMessage() {
    return sendMessage;
}

public void setSendMessage(String sendMessage) {
    this.sendMessage = sendMessage;
}

public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}}
```

## getMessage Class

```
 public void getMessage(){

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").getRef();
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                messagesList = new ArrayList<>(); //Initialize the list
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Messages messages = postSnapShot.child("messages").child(auth.getUid()).child("message").getValue(Messages.class);
                    messagesList.add(messages);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

[image]

I just want to get messages and timestamp.But I get that error;

```
/com.****.chat W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 05102018025211 found on class com.****.chat.Model.Messages
No setter/field for 05102018024849 found on class com.onsoftware.chat.Model.Messages
```

Comment: I believe you need to descend one level ; so getChildren of `child("message")` and iterate and then get value.

Comment: Right as Andy is pointing, just do this  databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("message").getRef();

Comment: So you want to get the messages under **`message`** node, in this case those two messages, right? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo yes right, two messages.

Comment: @Enivicivokkey Ok, I'll write you an answer in a short time.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference messageRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid).child("message").child(toUid).child("message");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Messages> messagesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Messages messages = ds.getValue(Messages.class);
            messagesList.add(messages);
            Log.d("TAG", messages.getSendMessage());
        }

        //Do what you need to do with your messagesList
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
messageRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In which the `toUid` is the uid of the user the receives the messages.

If you want at some point to try [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to can create a **[Chat App using Kotlin](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb)**.

Comment: Hi Enivicivokkey! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?